# Using reserved keywords as methods on Classes/Instances in Typescript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, typescript

If I use reserved keywords such as `delete` and `continue` as method names in Typescript classes, then I run into a problem with IE8.

For example:

```ts
class Foo {
    delete() : void {
        console.log('Delete called');
    }

    continue() : void {
        console.log('Continue called');
    }
}
```

generates the following javascript:

```js
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    Foo.prototype.delete = function () {
        console.log('Delete called');
    };

    Foo.prototype.continue = function () {
        console.log('Continue called');
    };
    return Foo;
})();
```

However, this does not fly well with IE8. IE8 would prefer to have this instead:

```js
var Bar = (function () {
    function Bar() {
    }
    Bar.prototype['delete'] = function () {
        console.log('Delete called');
    };

    Bar.prototype['continue'] = function () {
        console.log('Continue called');
    };
    return Bar;
})();
```

Is there a way I can retain the Typed goodness of Typescript while keeping my code IE8-well behaved?

In my particular case, I am trying to write a class which implements the [`ng.IHttpService` interface](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L556) and, hence, needs to have `delete` as an instance method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Foo {
    "delete"() : void {
        console.log('Delete called');
    }

    "continue"() : void {
        console.log('Continue called');
    }
}
```

translates to

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    Foo.prototype["delete"] = function () {
        console.log('Delete called');
    };

    Foo.prototype["continue"] = function () {
        console.log('Continue called');
    };
    return Foo;
})();
```

Note that I've never used TypeScript. I just went to their site, took a quick look at the specification PDF, found that string literals can be used, and tried it in the TypeScript playground.

Comment: Nice! I'll test if it still implements the interface correctly.

Comment: Yes, this still satisfied the `implements ng.IHttpService` requirement.